# Microsoft Excel - Use a drop down list to extract data from another workbook

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, vlookup

If i select an option from a drop down list, how do i then display data extracted from another workbook. So far, i have seen examples of showing single row data from another worksheet. But i have yet to see a method of extracting multiple rows and columns of data from a different workbook.

Week 1.xls:

```
     A             B                  C  
-------------------------------------------------
|   SKU   |    Description   |   Vendor Style   |
-------------------------------------------------
|         |                  |                  |
|  000001 |   Description 1  |    CA0080-03E    |
|  000002 |   Description 2  |    EX1134-59D    |
|  000003 |   Description 3  |    EM0132-59A    |
|  000004 |   Description 4  |    EW8694-52D    |
|  000005 |   Description 5  |    FC0003-18D    |
|  000006 |   Description 6  |    EK2273-59E    |
```

Master.xls:

```
 A             B                  C  
-------------------------------------------------      ________ _
|   SKU   |    Description   |   Vendor Style   |     |________|>|  <---Drop Down List
-------------------------------------------------
|         |                  |                  |
|         |                  |                  |
|         |                  |                  |
|         |                  |                  |
|         |                  |                  |
|         |                  |                  |
```

If i choose, e.g. Week 1 in the drop down list. I want the data from Week 1.xls to fill in the table in Master.xls.

If i choose, e.g. Week 2 in the drop down list. I want the data from Week 2.xls to fill in the table in Master.xls.

Is this possible? I'm thinking vlookups may be involved here in order to point to each workbook.

Thank you.

Comment: It will be harder if the other workbook is closed, but just use some form of lookup with the lookup value being the item selected in the drop down list.

Comment: Generally you'd use VBA for something like this.